# Scan for wireless stations

Tags: c, linux, c99

I'm developing a basic program for multicasting frames on a wireless network to determined stations, based on some rules. I use [lorcon](https://code.google.com/p/lorcon/) to handle the injection part, but I also need to look for which stations are present (both APs and clients).

I've googled a lot about how to do this, and I found that `iwlib.h` and `linux/wireless.h` can do the trick, but I wasn't able to see any clear example of how to use that libs out there.

Which of them is better for my purpose? Or are the same thing?
If you could link/post some examples of scanning it would be awesome ^^

Best Regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks that this is near impossible, so I decided to grab wireless packets with libpcap (`pcap/pcap.h`), and build a list based on its headers (src, dst, bssid).

This helped me a bit with the developing: http://www.tcpdump.org/pcap.html